# How to calculate number of repeated elements in a 1D array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a double array with size N with elements calculated by the code. And looks something like this:

a, b, a, a, b, c,...

So it has duplicate elements. For example a is repeated 10 times, b is repeated 12 times etc.

I want to output something like this:

a : 10

b : 12

What would be a good algorithm to do this?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the array?

Comment: See `std::map`, use the value in the array as the key in the map and the map value would be the count, as in `std::map<int, unsigned int>`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes. It can be sorted.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I tried something I read here, stackoverflow.com/questions/416237/… but It didn't seem to work for me. and because elements are double, I failed to use them as array dimension like this array[a][repeatedtime]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char y[] = { 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c' };
int count[52] = {0};

for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(x) / sizeof(char)); i++)
{
    if (y[i] >= 65 && y[i] <= 90)
        count[y[i] - 'A']++;
    else if (y[i] >= 97 && y[i] <= 122)
        count[(y[i] - 'a') + 26]++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
{
    if (i < 26 && count[i] > 0)
        cout << char('A' + i) << ": " << count[i] << endl;
    else if (i >= 26 && count[i] > 0)
        cout << char('a' + i - 26) << ": " << count[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: plus one for mentioning a different method for general use. I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

If the elements are floating point, the probability of two values being *exactly equal* is very low (due to how floating point numbers are represented).

You may want to calculate the absolute difference between two number and compare to some epsilon value like 1.0E-5.  If the difference is less than epsilon, consider the values equal.

One algorithm is to sort the array.  As long as consecutive values are "equal", increment the counter.

Comment: Thanks! Nice way to work around using characters and map.